# Vector definition through sympify method in Sympy

Tags: python, vector, sympy

I use Sympy in my Python project, were the string definition of the expression converted to Sympy through sympify method. For example:

```
import sympy as sp
exp1 = sp.sympify('Add(Rational(1, 5), pi)')
```

While I am able to describe almost all functionality, I ran into the problem of Vector description to be understood by sympify method. Vector definition in normal way:

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
R = CoordSys3D('R')
v = 3*R.i + 4*R.j + 5*R.k
```

Next example (one of a variety) is failing:

```
exp2 = sp.sympify('Vector(Coord3D().i*3, Coord3D().j*4, Coord3D().k*5')
```

I would like to keep Vector format to support the curl, divergence and gradient functionality. Definition of 1-row matrix does not suit here for me. Documentation research did not give results.

I would be grateful for an example or suggestion of the right way for the sympy.vector definition for the sympify method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a locals dictionary, will that do what you want:

```
>>> from sympy.vector import *
>>> sympify('Vector(R.i*3, R.j*4, R.k*5)',
... locals=dict(R=CoordSys3D('R'), Vector=Vector))
Vector(3*R.i, 4*R.j, 5*R.k)
>>> type(_)
<class 'sympy.vector.vector.Vector'>
```

Comment: Thank you @smichr, the suggestion is quite helpful!
Nevertheless, during the output of result value I have Attribute error:
`AttributeError: 'Vector' object has no attribute '_components'`. The case is repeated in my work environment and jupyter notebook.
May you know with what it related?

Comment: Not sure...try downloading the development version of SymPy.

Comment: I tested this case with Sympy 1.4 and 1.5b1 from GitHub. An error occurs in both cases. I have added the issue in the corresponding section of GitHub Sympy.